# Partial Differentiation: Suppose $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ and $x=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$. How to find $∂f/∂x$?

Tags: partial-derivative

Partial Differentiation: Suppose $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ and $x=r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$. How to find $∂f/∂x$?

I have the following question and no access to solutions.

The variables $x$, $y$, $z$ and $r$, $θ$, $φ$ are connected by the following equations:

\begin{align}
x&=r\sin(θ)\cos(φ) \\
y&=r\sin(θ)\sin(φ) \\
z&=r\cos(θ)
\end{align}

(a) Find $∂x/∂φ$, $∂y/∂φ$, and $∂z/∂φ$.

(b) Show that for any differentiable function $g(x,y,z)$ we have
$g_φ(x,y,z)=x\cdot g_y(x,y,z)−y\cdot g_x(x,y,z)$.

(c) Suppose $f(r,θ,φ)=\cosθ$. Find $∂f/∂x$, giving your answer in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$.

I am happy with parts a and b. Unfortunately, I am a little stuck with (c).

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thank-you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We use something called MathJax here to format mathematics so equations and expressions are easier to read. That's what I did in my edit to your question, and you can find a tutorial to learn how to do it yourself here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It's really easy to pick up, trust me.

Comment: Hi there mate! Thank you for pointing this out. Rather new here as you likely guessed! I will use this going forward. Cheers.

Comment: You're certainly welcome; happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use that

$$f(r,\theta,\varphi)=\cos \theta=\dfrac{z}{r}=\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.$$

Comment: Mate, thank you for this. Still not getting it. Clearly I've reached my saturation point today...

Comment: Note that $f=\cos \theta.$ From the definition of $z=r\cos\theta$ you have $\cos \theta =z/r.$ Now, just check that $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ (note that it is a parametrization of the sphere of radius $r$).

Comment: Understand that bit mate. It's the next step which has me flummoxed...

Comment: Now you have to get the derivative with respect to $x$ of the quotient $\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.$

Comment: so $df/dx = -xz(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(-3/2)$

Comment: I think that is the correct answer.

Comment: Trying to find a way to message you directly and thank you, but I'm yet to master navigating Stack Exchange. Thank you very much indeed for this mate. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. It is a pleasure to give hints when the OP does the work.